# How is string used for indices in the following function?

Tags: python

Can you explain to me what the following function does?
for example:

```
value = value_expr["A_Const"]["val"]
```

Is it a dictionary or a dataframe?

If it is one of these two cases, then what is its working method?

```
def getValue(self, value_expr):
  if "A_Const" in value_expr:
    value = value_expr["A_Const"]["val"]
    if "String" in value:
        return "'" + value["String"]["str"]+"\'"
    elif "Integer" in value:
        self.isInt = True
        self.val = value["Integer"]["ival"]
        return str(value["Integer"]["ival"])
    else:
        raise "unknown Value in Expr"
  elif "TypeCast" in value_expr:
    if len(value_expr["TypeCast"]['typeName']['TypeName']['names'])==1:
        return value_expr["TypeCast"]['typeName']['TypeName']['names'][0]['String']['str']+" '"+value_expr["TypeCast"]['arg']['A_Const']['val']['String']['str']+"'"
    else:
        if value_expr["TypeCast"]['typeName']['TypeName']['typmods'][0]['A_Const']['val']['Integer']['ival']==2:
            return value_expr["TypeCast"]['typeName']['TypeName']['names'][1]['String']['str']+" '"+value_expr["TypeCast"]['arg']['A_Const']['val']['String']['str']+ "' month"
        else:
            return value_expr["TypeCast"]['typeName']['TypeName']['names'][1]['String']['str']+" '"+value_expr["TypeCast"]['arg']['A_Const']['val']['String']['str']+ "' year"
  else:
    print(value_expr.keys())
    raise "unknown Value in Expr"
```

Comment: It could be either, or anything that supports lookup by string. Do you want gory details about hashes and buckets or are you asking something else?

Comment: It certainly looks like a dictionary given `value_expr.keys()`, though it could still be a custom object, perhaps one that inherits from the dictionary class. If you want to know how dictionaries work, there are numerous tutorials. If you want to know what that method does, we don't have enough context. Some sort of extracting values from an abstract syntax tree.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's most likely a standard python dictionary. Checking `key in d` and then immediately calling `d[key]` is very typical of a python dict. If you somehow have an object in your code and you're unsure of what type it is, then you can always use the python built-in `type` function. Following are a few examples:

```py
l = list([1, 2, 5])
print(type(l))
# >>> <class 'list'>

d = dict(a=5, b=7)
print(type(d))
# >>> <class 'dict'>

s = str("Hi")
print(type(s))
# >>> <class 'str'>

i = int(42)
print(type(i))
# >>> <class 'int'>
```

Try using this function to check the type of your `value_expr` object. Hope this helps!